# Adding a new word to each subsequent cell in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been working on this code that takes misspelled words from a document and then turns them into a table with all the misspelled words on one column. Then the words are spellchecked and the corrections appear on the other column. My code does everything that I want it to, however only the first word appears on each cell. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub SuperSpellCheck()
Dim doc1 As Document
Dim doc2 As Document
Dim tb As Table
Set doc1 = ActiveDocument
Set doc2 = Documents.Add
doc1.Activate
Dim badw As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim sugg As SpellingSuggestions    
Dim sug As Variant
err = doc1.SpellingErrors.Count
For Each badw In doc1.SpellingErrors
doc2.Range.InsertAfter badw & vbCr
Next
doc2.Activate
Set tb = ActiveDocument.Content.ConvertToTable(Separator:=wdSeparateByParagraphs, NumColumns:=1,                     
NumRows:=ActiveDocument.SpellingErrors.Count, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)
With tb
    .Style = "Table Grid"
     .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
     .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
     .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
     .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
     .Columns.Add
     .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
     .PreferredWidth = 100
  End With
err2 = ActiveDocument.SpellingErrors.Count
i = 1
Set sugg = doc2.Range.GetSpellingSuggestions
For Each rng In doc2.Range.SpellingErrors
With rng
If sugg.Count > 0 Then
Set sug = .GetSpellingSuggestions
tb.Cell(i, 2).Range.InsertAfter sug(1)
End If
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: See: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-45943.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not connected to your problem but you need to change these lines

```
Err = doc1.SpellingErrors.Count
err2 = ActiveDocument.SpellingErrors.Count
```

To:

```
Dim errors1 as Long, dim errors2 as Long
errors1 = doc1.SpellingErrors.Count
errors2 = doc2.SpellingErrors.Count
```

`Err` is an object in VBA that holds the errors generated by your code. You also haven't declared those variables. Add `Option Explicit` at the very top of your code module and you will be alerted to any undeclared variables. To turn this on automatically in future go to Tools | Options | Editor and ensure that Require Variable Declaration is checked.

I would change

```
Dim sugg As SpellingSuggestions    
Dim sug As Variant
```

to

```
   Dim docSugg As SpellingSuggestions
   Dim rngSugg As SpellingSuggestions
   Dim sug As SpellingSuggestion
```

This will make it clearer what each of these represents.
`SpellingSuggestions` is a collection of `SpellingSuggestion` objects so you can use `sug` to loop through the collection.

```
   i = 1
   Set sugg = doc2.Range.GetSpellingSuggestions
   For Each rng In doc2.Range.SpellingErrors
      With rng
         If sugg.Count > 0 Then
            Set sug = .GetSpellingSuggestions
            tb.Cell(i, 2).Range.InsertAfter sug(1)
         End If
      End With
   Next
```

In this block of code you start off by setting the undeclared variable `i` to a value of 1, but you don't then increase that value. This will result in all your spelling suggestions being inserted in the same cell. Also, when you insert the spelling suggestion you only ever insert the first one as you don't have a means of looping through them. So I would rewrite this as:

```
   i = 1
   Set docSugg = doc2.Range.GetSpellingSuggestions
   For Each rng In doc2.Range.SpellingErrors
      With rng
         If docSugg.Count > 0 Then
            Set rngSugg = .GetSpellingSuggestions
            For Each sug In rngSugg
               tb.Cell(i, 2).Range.InsertAfter sug
            Next
         End If
      End With
      i = i + 1
   Next
```

EDIT: If you only want the first suggested spelling then use:

```
   i = 1
   Set docSugg = doc2.Range.GetSpellingSuggestions
   For Each rng In doc2.Range.SpellingErrors
      With rng
         If docSugg.Count > 0 Then
            Set rngSugg = .GetSpellingSuggestions
            tb.Cell(i, 2).Range.InsertAfter rngSugg(1)
         End If
      End With
      i = i + 1
   Next
```

Comment: When I made the changes that you have stated, I got the correct words for each misspelled word on the correct cell (which is great), however in many the cells there are many different words all stuck together. For example, there is one cell containing the text "Stratgfies." Next to that is a cell containing the text "StratifiesStrategies" 
I wanted to only the first SpellingSuggestion for each of the misspelled words in each of the cell. 

 That is why I put the "1" after the "sug".

Comment: @CountSpergulia - your question was "only the first word appears on each cell. What am I doing wrong?" - hence my original answer, which I have now edited.

Comment: It works!!!! Now just one last question if you don't mind: Why the need for two SpellingSuggestion collections?

Comment: @CountSpergulia - beyond the fact they were in your original code, none.